# Can we merge the google-scripts tag with google-apps-script?

Tags: discussion, support, stack-overflow, retag-request, synonym-request

[google-scripts](/questions/tagged/google-scripts) and [google-apps-script](/questions/tagged/google-apps-script) appear to be talking about the same language, and just fragment the discussion. Admittedly Google may have caused that by referring to the script alternatively as GoogleScript and giving it the .gs extension when saved, but then in documentation it’s all under “Google Apps Script”.

Either way, is there a reason for two separate tags?

Also, as a newcomer, is it even possible to merge two tags, and am I asking this stuff in the right place? (<strike>ironically</strike> Coincidentally the tag-synonyms tag here seems to answer that question. :))

Comment: One, that's not irony.  Two, yes, and yes.

Comment: @djechlin, touche. edited to "coincidentally".

Comment: As of today, there are just over 100 questions tagged [tag:google-scripts], more than half have both tags. Working our way down...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've retagged questions to [google-apps-script](/questions/tagged/google-apps-script).

The [google-scripts](/questions/tagged/google-scripts) will be deleted in the next 24 hours.

Comment: Great! Could you look at [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181610/merge-google-docs-script-into-google-apps-script) too? It's similar, about the [tag:google-docs-script] tag. I've retagged all those questions already, so the tag is ready to burn.

Comment: This tag is alread dead, as you can see, there is no *info* tab. A tag with no question is deleted after 24h.

Comment: Aha - didn't know that. I kept waiting to see the tag disappear from my "Favorite Tags" list.

Comment: Thanks! New to contributing to SO, and it's nice to feel like I'm contributing something.