# Merge [google-docs-script] into [google-apps-script]

Tags: support, stack-overflow, retag-request, synonym-request, burninate-request

[google-docs-script](/questions/tagged/google-docs-script) is a synonym for [google-apps-script](/questions/tagged/google-apps-script). Almost half of the 75 questions tagged so far are ALSO tagged [google-apps-script](/questions/tagged/google-apps-script) already, so we'd benefit from elimination of the redundancy.

Could the tagged questions be merged, and [google-docs-script](/questions/tagged/google-docs-script) burninated?

**Edit:** As of 28-May-2013, there are 0 remaining questions in [google-docs-script](/questions/tagged/google-docs-script). Thanks to whoever pitched in!

Comment: `google-docs-script` isn't that new.  The [oldest unedited question with that tag is from December 2011](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8653565/168868).  Regardless, +1 for the merge.

Comment: @Charles - Righto, it was the wiki that was created just 3 days ago. The [Info Link](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-docs-script/info) is a bit misleading, I thought it was reporting when the tag was created. Red herring text removed - the point really is just about redundancy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All questions formerly in [google-docs-script](/questions/tagged/google-docs-script) have been merged into [google-apps-script](/questions/tagged/google-apps-script), and [google-docs-script](/questions/tagged/google-docs-script) is no more.